# Using lodash (or equivalent) _.get() function to get object by reference and not value

Tags: javascript, json, underscore.js, lodash

the _.get() function allows you to use a string to deep get value from Json object.
However it gets value and not reference, is an equivalent command (or diff way) to get reference to Json object

example:

```
var object = { 'a': [{ 'b': { 'c': 3 } }] };

const r = _.get(object, 'a[0].b');
r <<< is new object not a ref.
```

thanks,

Sean

Comment: What do you mean by reference? A reference to the number `3`?

Comment: You can get the object `{ 'c': 3 }` by using `var ref = _.get(object, 'a[0].b')`. `_.get` will return a reference to that object. Changing `ref.c` will change the original object

Comment: Sorry I mean reference to the object, I will fix the example

Comment: _"`r` is new object not a ref"_. Well try changing it's properties and notice what happens to the original object. `r` references the object `{ 'c': 3 }` from the original object. This can be proven by checking `object.a[0].b === r`

Comment: according to my tests and this https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/2638 it's not the case

Comment: The issue in the github link is totaly different. They are trying to get the root object itself. You are trying to get a nested object which does return a reference: https://repl.it/repls/UselessVeneratedRobodoc

Comment: I tried it with nested and had same result, changing the result of my _.get did not change the original Json.

Comment: https://repl.it/repls/UselessVeneratedRobodoc

Comment: BTW, you can't replace a variable and expect the original object to get affected. I mean `r = { some: "other object" }` will not work. It will change the reference itself. `r` will not reference your object any more, it will reference the new one you just assigned. References just don't work like that.

Comment: BTW #2: javascript doesn't really have references like another language like c# or c++ does: https://stackoverflow.com/q/518000/9867451 . If it did and `r` was truly a reference, then replacing `r` with a new object would affect the original object

Comment: This example is pretty much what you are trying to do: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3638034/9867451

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `_.get` function does not create a new object. It is already returning a "reference".

```js
const object = { 'a': [{ 'b': { 'c': 3 } }] };

const r = _.get(object, 'a[0].b');

console.log(r === object.a[0].b); // true
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```